# Download Azure Cloud Services package and configuration without REST API

Tags: rest, api, azure, service, cloud

Is there any way to download Azure Cloud Services package and configuration files without using Azure REST API?

Thank you in advance

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know, if you want to get the Azure Cloud Services configuration, you could use portal directly download it.

You could open azure portal and find the Configuration and click download. It is the configuration files.

Details you could refer to this image:

[image]

But if you want to download the Azure Cloud Services package, I think you could only using azure rest api to download it.

Besides, the  Azure Cloud Services package is generate according to your cloud servers running application, you could directly use CSPack command-line tool to generate it in the local. More details, you could refer to this [article](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cloud-services/cloud-services-model-and-package#servicepackagecspkg).

Comment: Hi Brando,

Thank you for your help but in my portal I can't find "Configuration". Is there any chance this to be a deprecated function?

Thanks

Comment: Do you used the azure classic portal not the new portal(portal.azure.com)?

Comment: I'm using the new portal. Just checked the old one and it looks much different than the photo provided by you?

Comment: Do you create the classic could service in the old portal(Using azure service management)? Not the new portal?